# Forward gestures to UITableViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipangesturerecognizer, uitouch

I've an UISplitViewController-Subclass with two UITableViewControllers (master & detail) in my Storyboard.

My BOSplitViewController is extended by a subview to draw in it.

```
_linienView = [[BODrawLinienView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];

[self.view addSubview:_linienView];
```

In BODrawLinienView i've implemented my UIPanGestureRecognizer to Draw UIBezierPaths.

```
    _panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(recognizedGesture:)];
    _panRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
    _panRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
    _panRecognizer.delegate = self;
    _panRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;

    [self addGestureRecognizer:_panRecognizer];
```

And the UIGesturerecognizerDelegate methods are implemented there, too.

```
#pragma mark - <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGestureRecognizer {

    CGPoint velocity = [panGestureRecognizer velocityInView:self];

    return fabs(velocity.y) < fabs(velocity.x); // < >
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {

    return YES;
}
```

The check for velocity in `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:` allows me to avoid vertical events handled by the recognizer, who only should accept more or less horizontal events.

But all events avoided by this check aren't forwarded to the UITableViews in the SplitViewControlles ViewControllers.

EDIT: I've prepared a demo-project of this behavior on [my Dropbox directory](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7kyflxg1f3lf21j/AABtfBBLhj6BTXzYXLlpVATHa?dl=0%20my%20Dropbox)

Does anybody know how to realize forwarding of events to these Views?